# PTIJ: Is Punxsutawney Phil assur?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

> Each year, the town of Punxsutawney celebrates the legendary groundhog with a festive atmosphere of music and food. During the ceremony, which begins well before the winter sunrise, Phil (the groundhog) emerges from his temporary home.... According to the tradition, if Phil sees his shadow and returns to his hole, he has predicted six more weeks of winter-like weather. If Phil does not see his shadow, he has predicted an "early spring ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punxsutawney_Phil))

Aside from the question of if Phil, who at certain times cannot see his shadow, is a demon (see Gittin 61), my question is is this a form of divination and therefore forbidden?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: @isaac this post doesn't qualify as PTIJ. It doesn't "misinterpret a real Torah concept or Jewish text" or "apply a distinctly Torah style (e.g. Talmudic analysis) to an irrelevant topic". Consider: what if a Jewish governor of Pennsylvania is asked to perform the ceremony (whatever that entails)?

Comment: @DoubleAA Are you implying that this is a real question?

Comment: @Bachrach44 I'm saying it doesn't fit the definition of a PTIJ post per the policy. I don't know what 'real question' means. Whether or not the OP intended it as PTIJ, it doesn't seem to qualify under the policy.